# Cannot Load .mat file containing a struct in python 3x

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, scipy

I have a .mat file which contains a struct and want to load that struct in Python
I am trying with scipy and loadmat...

```
import scipy.io as sio
file = sio.loadmat('Data.mat')
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

> MatReadWarning: Duplicate variable name "None" in stream - replacing previous with new
>   Consider mio5.varmats_from_mat to split file into single variable files
>     matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)

Does anyone had a similar case or might have an idea on what I am doing wrong?

note: I am using Python3x and Scipy v1.0.0

Comment: Is that just a warning or an actual error?  In other words, did it produce a `file` variable?  If so, did you explore its contents?  We may need to know something about the source `struct`.

Comment: The warning suggests an alternative reader, `io.matlab.mio5.varmats_from_mat(file_obj)`.  Did you look at its docs and/or test it?  You can see its code in `scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py`